# How do I run a .sql3 file that I received when pulling my database from Google App Engine?

Tags: sql, database, google-app-engine, sqlite

The Google page on uploading and downloading datastores is pretty useless, but I've gotten this far. Now I need to get the data in the .sql3 into whatever database it was originally stored in.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is for an [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database.  Try looking at the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html), it has info for how to create a database and load data into it.

Comment: The result from downloading the datastore from GAE is in fact an sqlite database. The problem is that it appears that it needs to be processed by something else for it to be usable. Right now it contains two tables, results and bulkloader_database_signature. Is there some GAE program I need to run on my computer to get the database into a readable, usable format?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the bulkloader's --dump functionality, it's not the intention that you directly access the downloaded sqlite database. Instead, you should restore it to an App Engine instance - either in production or on the dev-appserver - using the bulkloader's --restore flag.

Comment: That clears a lot up:) I'm trying to get access to the database so that I can migrate it to a new RoR application. What do would you suggest for doing that?

Comment: Export the data as CSV or another format that you can read, and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do to download and then restore data locally. You can modify this slightly to upload data to a remote datastore.

1) Make sure you have the remote_api enabled in your app.yaml

```
handlers:
- url: /remote_api
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py
  login: admin
```

Be sure and do an update to upload the app.yaml to your GAE app.

2) Download data

```
python appcfg.py download_data --application=app-name --url=http://www.app-domain.org/remote_api --email=user@gmail.com --filename=data.dat
```

This produces several files, but we're primarily interested in the data.dat file (which is in the sqlite format).

3) Restore db locally (must be running)

```
python appcfg.py upload_data --filename=data.dat --url=http://localhost:8080/remote_api /app-folder
```

You can modify the URL param to move the data wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that you have downloaded file named . You need to run following command:

```
sqlite3 <sql3_filename>
```